# few price for 1 product in shopping cart Yii

Tags: php, yii, shopping-cart

I have some problem with fulfill add few price for one product into basket. I have 2 models: Goods and ColorGoods. ColorsGoods model has foreign key to the model Goods and field price.Every Color has various price .Also I have a form where display a good with all color which it has. I need when I choose one or more color via checkbox in basket - it count price respectively price which has color.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in view:

```
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([]);

    ...
    # here colors is getColors() method in $model class creating relation
    foreach ($model->colors as $color){
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='color' value='{$color->price}'> {$color->name} <br>"

    }

  $form->field($order, 'total')->textInput(['id' => 'total-price', 'value' => 0]);

    ...

    ActiveForm::end();

<script>
  $('input[name="color"]').change(function(e){
    var total = $("#total-price").val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
    } else {
      total = parseInt(total) - parseInt($(this).val());
    }

    $("#total-price").val(total);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But I use shopping cart extension in yii 1. And that must be implement in Model.